# Question about deprecated-copy-with-user-provided-copy warning

Tags: c++

I try to define a vector class based on template, but got this warning message

```
 warning: definition of implicit copy constructor for 'Vec<double, 3>' is deprecated because it has a user-provided copy assignment operator [-Wdeprecated-copy-with-user-provided-copy]
        Vec &operator=(const Vec &t)
             ^
...test_temp.cpp:86:17: note: in implicit copy constructor for 'Vec<double, 3>' first required here
    auto vadd = v1 + v2;
                ^
1 warning generated.
```

I'm not sure what are good practices here. Should I just label the assignment operator as a default one, or just add `-Wno-deprecated-copy-with-user-provided-copy`? Are there other solutions to solve this issue?

This is a test file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

    template <typename T, uint Size>
    class Vec
    {
    public:
        static const int NUM_COMPONENTS = Size;
        T Components[NUM_COMPONENTS];
        Vec() {}
        Vec(T init)
        {
            for (uint i = 0; i < this->NUM_COMPONENTS; i++)
            {
                this->Components[i] = init;
            }
        }

        Vec<T,Size> operator+(const Vec &t) const
        {
            assert(this->NUM_COMPONENTS == t.NUM_COMPONENTS);
            Vec<T,Size> result;
            for (uint i = 0; i < this->NUM_COMPONENTS; i++)
            {
                result[i] = this->Components[i] + t.Components[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        Vec<T,Size> operator-(const Vec &t) const
        {
            assert(this->NUM_COMPONENTS == t.NUM_COMPONENTS);
            Vec<T,Size> result;
            for (uint i = 0; i < this->NUM_COMPONENTS; i++)
            {
                result[i] = this->Components[i] - t.Components[i];
            }
            return result;
        }

        T &operator[](uint index)
        {
            assert(index >= 0);
            assert(index < this->NUM_COMPONENTS);
            return this->Components[index];
        }
        
        const T &operator[](uint index) const
        {
            assert(index >= 0);
            assert(index < this->NUM_COMPONENTS);
            return this->Components[index];
        }

        Vec<T,Size> &operator=(const Vec<T,Size> &t)
        {
            assert(this->NUM_COMPONENTS == t.NUM_COMPONENTS);
            for (uint i = 0; i < this->NUM_COMPONENTS; i++)
            {
                this->Components[i] = t.Components[i];
            }
            return *this;
        }
        void Show()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this->NUM_COMPONENTS; i++)
            {
                printf("%lf ", 1.0 * this->Components[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    };

int main() {
    Vec<double, 3> v1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        v1[i] = 2.0;
    }
    Vec<double, 3> v2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        v2[i] = 3.0;
    }
    auto vadd = v1 + v2;
    std::cout << "test";
    vadd.Show();
    return 0;
}
```

I set cmake flag as:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic")
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: It's just a warning.  "Deprecation" merely means "we don't like this any more". The only data member is a simple array, so there's no serious danger in using the default dumb copy.

Comment: What is `uint`? `T &operator[](uint index) { assert(index >= 0);` implies that `uint` is a _signed_ type - which would be utterly confusing. Please use standard types or show your definitions.

Comment: This `assert(this->NUM_COMPONENTS == t.NUM_COMPONENTS);` isn't doing anything any of the three times it appears, because it's comparing a static variable to itself (both operands are fetched from the exact same type, to wit `Vec<T,Size>`)

Comment: (It's also confusing that parameters and return types sometimes use `Vec<T,Size>` and sometimes use the injected name `Vec` alone.   Both mean the same thing.)

Comment: Anyway, you could just add `constexpr Vec(const Vec&) = default;` to get rid of the warning - and it looks like you could replace your own copy assignment operator with `constexpr Vec& operator=(const Vec&) = default;` too.

Comment: `Vec<T,Size> &operator=(const Vec<T,Size> &t) { assert(this->NUM_COMPONENTS == t.NUM_COMPONENTS);` -- I don't agree with using `assert` here, even if your intention was to determine if `*this` had the same size as `t`.  The purpose of `operator=` is to make the left side of the `=` equal to the right side of the `=`, regardless of what the left side is equal to at the time `=` is called.  For example: `int a = 10; int b = 3; a = b;` -- There is no check to see if `a` is currently 3, thus there should be no check necessary for `*this`, since the current object is going to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't declare the copy assignment operator at all. The implicitly-defined one does already do exactly what you want.

Always follow the rule-of-zero where you can: Don't declare either destructor, copy/move constructor or copy/move assignment operator. And if you *do* need any of them, then follow the rule-of-three/five and also define *all* of them, because if that is the case you almost surely need custom behavior in them as well.

That's *the* most important rule for C++ class design. Unfortunately the language itself doesn't enforce it. However, the implicit declaration of the copy constructor when the copy assignment operator has been user-declared has been deprecated in order to support that rule. That's what the compiler is warning you about.

The solution is *not* to add a copy constructor. Defining it to be exactly the same as the one the compiler will generate will always result in worse code.

Answer (score -1):

I just found that adding a copy constructor (I forgot to add it) can solve the issue, just post an potential answer here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T, uint Size>
class Vec
{
public:
    static const int NUM_COMPONENTS = Size;
    T Components[NUM_COMPONENTS];
    Vec() {}
    Vec(T init)
    {
        for (uint i = 0; i < this->NUM_COMPONENTS; i++)
        {
            this->Components[i] = init;
        }
    }

    Vec(const Vec &src)
    {
        assert(this->NUM_COMPONENTS == src.NUM_COMPONENTS);
        for (uint i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        {
            this->Components[i] = src[i];
        }
    }

    Vec operator+(const Vec &t) const
    {
        assert(this->NUM_COMPONENTS == t.NUM_COMPONENTS);
        Vec<T, Size> result;
        for (uint i = 0; i < this->NUM_COMPONENTS; i++)
        {
            result[i] = this->Components[i] + t.Components[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    Vec operator-(const Vec &t) const
    {
        assert(this->NUM_COMPONENTS == t.NUM_COMPONENTS);
        Vec<T, Size> result;
        for (uint i = 0; i < this->NUM_COMPONENTS; i++)
        {
            result[i] = this->Components[i] - t.Components[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    T &operator[](int index)
    {
        assert(index >= 0);
        assert(index < this->NUM_COMPONENTS);
        return this->Components[index];
    }

    const T &operator[](int index) const
    {
        assert(index >= 0);
        assert(index < this->NUM_COMPONENTS);
        return this->Components[index];
    }

    Vec &operator=(const Vec &t)
    {
        assert(this->NUM_COMPONENTS == t.NUM_COMPONENTS);
        for (uint i = 0; i < this->NUM_COMPONENTS; i++)
        {
            this->Components[i] = t.Components[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }
    void Show()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->NUM_COMPONENTS; i++)
        {
            printf("%lf ", 1.0 * this->Components[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vec<double, 3> v1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        v1[i] = 2.0;
    }
    Vec<double, 3> v2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        v2[i] = 3.0;
    }
    auto vadd = v1 + v2;
    std::cout << "test";
    vadd.Show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the copy constructor and assignment? You don't need them at all. Remove both and the compiler will also be happy. Follow the rule-of-zero where you can and the rule-of-three/five where you can't.